# Retain horizontal and vertical scroll positions in a form within an iframe when it reloads after submit

Tags: javascript, forms, scroll

I am developing a web based simulation. It has an iframe from where the user can access various forms, which are essentially independent html pages within the iframe. After they click on the submit button on a form, the form reloads with fresh information. However, I need it to reposition itself to the place where it was at the time when the button was submitted. I am able to do this when the form is independently loaded on Chrome without the iframe. But it does not work from within the iframe. The code I used is:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  sessionStorage.scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
    $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollTop);
  }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.